# How to Look Up a Token Policy ID from The Smart Contract Validator

Tags: token, smart-contract, policy, mkvalidator

I have attached a token to the datum and sent it to the smart contract, now I need the validator to check that the token has a certain policy ID before it allows the contract to proceed.

How do I do that?

Comment: How did you attach the token to the datum? did you do something like ```<policy id>.<token name>``` as a ```BuiltinByteString``` ? I'm asking since the Datum is supposed to only have data

Comment: Please check the answer to my previous question. Someone told me to send along the token with the datum maybe attached isn't the right word but I don't know what would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following

```
info :: TxInfo
info = scriptContextTxInfo ctx

inputValue :: [Value]
inputValue = map (txOutValue . txInInfoResolved) (txInfoInputs info)

checkValueHasToken :: Value -> Bool
checkValueHasToken val = case flattenValue val of
        (pol, tn, amt) -> pol == knownPolicyID 

checkInputHasToken :: Bool
checkInputHasToken = any checkValueHashToken inputValue
```